# How to know whether a given client-side startup script is already registered in an asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net, startupscript

I have a asp.net page, and would like to know whether "script1" is already registered as a startup script or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Me.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("clientScript")